# Confusion related to optimization of log(det(X)) function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have this confusion related to optimization of the log(det(X)) function. I didn't get how it implicitly maintains the constraint of X being positive definite.

For eg if I have a matrix

```
0 1 2
2 4 5
1 6 7
```

This matrix is not positive definite. However, its determinant is equal to  7 and log(7) is still ok. So I didn't get how the log barrier prevents X from not being positive definite

here is the [paper](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Pubs/CovSel_JMLR.pdf%E2%80%8E) I am referring to

[image]

Comment: I don't see any optimization in your question. I assume the quantity optimized is $\log\det X$, but is it minimized or maximized, and on which set?

Comment: Eh, it doesn't (i.e., it's not a "barrier" per se). Positive definiteness is a *requirement* for optimizing $\log\det$.

Comment: @JohnMoeller. I didn't get how positive definiteness is a requirement for optimizing logdet

Comment: Hm, that's fair. More of a convention, I suppose. You only see it in problems where $X$ is symmetric and positive definite. In that setting you're guaranteed that $\log\det X$ is real and concave, so it has a unique maximum. You're right in that lack of symmetry or the presence of negative eigenvalues doesn't *prevent* $X$ from being positive definite. I don't see how there's some kind of implicit enforcement, however. Do you have a citation for that? Maybe I can help you make sense of it.

Comment: @JohnMoeller. I have added more info in the question. Also a reference to the paper

Comment: @JohnMoeller. Also I didn't get what you mean by that lack of symmetry or the presence of negative eigenvalues doesn't prevent X from being positive definite. If the matrix has negative eigen values it is definitely not positive definite

Comment: Correct. I worded that badly. I meant that "Lack of symmetry or presence of negative eigenvalues doesn't prevent you from finding an $X$ such that $\log\det X$ is real."

Comment: Ah, ok. The way to see this is that $\log\det$ doesn't "maintain" the constraint. It's a constraint that emerges from the formulation. All the above is saying is that "in order to minimize the objective, $\log\det(S+U)$ has to be real, so $S+U$ had better be P.D."  That's not strictly true (for the reasons that you pointed out), but it's the easiest way to guarantee it.